# Disable APC Cache for cached files?

Tags: php, apc, opcode, opcode-cache

I have a quite large website, in which there is a forum powered by phpBB. I have APC enabled with 1Gb of RAM. **phpBB generates a lot of php files of cache** (60 000-70 000 in my case), and they rapidly **fill up APC memory**. I was thinking to disable apc caching of such files through the `apc.filter` option. In your opinion, does it make sense?

Comment: great question; wondered this before, myself

Comment: Could you explain a little more? I'm very aware of APC's abilities, but not of phpBB's "php files of cache." Do you simply mean cache variables in APC?

Comment: I mean tons of filesystem cache files generated by phpbb. Query results, templates, are all cached as php files, and so apc cache them. However, filesystem cache is not the only caching system allowed by phpbb3. For example, it is possible to use memcache

Comment: if you have a quite large website i guess you can permit to buy a server with more than 1GB that would solve all problems. plus such servers doesnt' cost more than 20-30 bucks/month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't run phpBB in a long time, so my answer is conditional:

- If there's actual PHP code in those cache files, there's worth to be had in caching in APC. I might go a step further and say that they're incredibly valuable to cache, since phpBB feels these files will be used often enough to have been worth caching.
- If they contain static HTML or other content that's not PHP, filter them out or convince phpBB to give them an alternate extension.

How fast are you running through your data in APC? If you're cycling through cache misses incredibly quickly, you've got a problem. If the number of misses stays constant and low over time I wouldn't worry about it. If you're storing lots of user data in APC that might be a way to shave it down. apc.php is a great way to get more details on what APC is up to, but remember it's an expensive page to load.

(have worked on several PHP sites dealing with millions to tens of millions of unique visitors per day)

Comment: For phpBB, the former case applies -- the cache files contain serialized data. As such, holding them (or even just a few of them) in memory is extremely helpful, as it'll keep phpBB from having to go to the database as often.